# Why gamers dont wear glasses

Tags: medications, eye

I noticed on every gaming channel no one is wearing glasses and thats bad for a eye to live i think gamers like "DanTDM" is playing games everyday which is very bad but i found glasses that have yellow filter but i use this app "f.lux" its to prevent someone to be awake and i use my PC everyday at 15:00 to 22:02 in Lithuania and it just puts a yellow filter or orange filter i think but its ment make for people that play games and it looks like this:
[image: Filter]

I wasn't able to do a screenshot beacuse it doesnt capture the filter but the program works like this
Heres another one:
[image: Animated Image]
So why gamers don't wear glasses?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about health.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! Your post seems to not be about a health issue. Thus it will probably be closed. If you will like to edit it that is your choice and may delay its being closed. Consulting the Help Center will help you construct a better post. Good luck and see you around!

Comment: studies suggest that childhood is the most important time (sunlight during this stage seems to play an important role in eye health. The gamer you are talking about could have spend enough time outdoor during their childhood).

Answer (score 1):

Continuous watching of monitor causes eye dryness that's because we force our eyes no to blink each and every 6-7 secs but to some maximum time we keep it open that causes pain in eyes and red devil look.
Gamer glass act as a blue filter. As blue is a color which signal our brain that sun isn't set even after sunset this in turn reduces the secretion of melatonin(sleep hormone).
Gamers have intense passion and accuracy to achieve the target and to win the game they need to watch the screen properly (my experience in Counter Strike).

Comment: Welcome to Health SE. Thank you for your post, however post here generally have links or research to support the content. Adding that will make your post follow Health SE guidelines. See the Help Center on how to write a accurate post.   Thanks and see you around :)